# Optional(not random) argument in URL patterns

Tags: django

How can I pass optional argument in url patterns(not random)?

/new/

/new/save-and-add-new/

```
url(
    regex=r'^~new/[save-and-add-new]/$',
    view=views.BudgetCreateView.as_view(),
    name='create'
),
```

I need to use this in:

```
def get_success_url(self):
   if save_and_add_new_argument_in_url:
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('item:new'))
   return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('item:list'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url(
regex=r'^~new/(?P<param>\w+)/$',
view=views.BudgetCreateView.as_view(),
name='create'
),
url(
regex=r'^~new/$',
view=views.BudgetCreateView.as_view(),
name='create'
),
```

Then

```
def get_success_url(self, param=None):
   if param is not None:
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('item:new'))
   return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('item:list'))
```